# Access the response of a same-origin iFrame window?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have `example.com/outer` which iFrames `example.com/inner`. Making a get request to `example.com/inner` returns a PDF response object, which automatically downloads to the browser.

Given that these are same-origin iFrames, how can I use Javascript / jQuery to access the response of `example.com/inner` as a Blob when it is loaded inside `example.com/outer`?

Comment: i dont think you can access the response itself. you can read the dom, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message from child -> parent. However, you can't just use jQuery inside the parent to receive data if the child hasn't sent it in a message.

**Child**

```
parent.postMessage("Hello World!, "*");
```

**Parent**

```
function listenToChild(event){
    console.log(event);
}
window.addEventListener("message", listenToChild, false);
```